# Gradient color is truncated in UILabel in non-english language

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient

I want to set gradient color to the text in UILabel but find that if the text is non-english language, the gradient color truncated. Is this a bug?

[image: images]

Code is shown below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 0, 0)];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
    label.text = @"Your Name";
    [label sizeToFit];

    UIImage *gradientImage = [self.class gradientImageWithSize:label.frame.size beginColor:UIColor.redColor endColor:UIColor.yellowColor];

    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gradientImage];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}

+ (UIImage *)gradientImageWithSize:(CGSize)size beginColor:(UIColor *)beginColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor {
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)beginColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)endColor.CGColor];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5);
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size);
    [gradientLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Just replace the label.text to:

```
label.text = @"你的名字";

Or

label.text = @"君の名は";
```

then it happens. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the bug of UIKit.
Size of the tile gets wrong when label has none English Characters.

If you want to mask gradient color on your label, just use masking view for your label.

#### ObjectiveC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 0, 0)];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
    label.text = @"君の名は";
    [label sizeToFit];


    UIView *gradientView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:label.frame];
    label.frame = gradientView.bounds;

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)UIColor.redColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5);

    [gradientView.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    [gradientView addSubview:label];
    [gradientView setMaskView:label];
}
```

#### Swift

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0))
    label.text = "君の名は"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    label.sizeToFit()

    let gradientView = UIView(frame: label.frame)
    label.frame = gradientView.bounds
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    gradientView.addSubview(label)
    gradientView.mask = label

    self.view.addSubview(gradientView)
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a nice solution :)